# How to add an extra line to DetailsSupportFragment?

Tags: android, leanback

How to add an extra line to DetailsSupportFragment in leanback library?

I know how add line in DetailsOverviewRow, but it should be after DetailsOverviewRow

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TO add extra line to in details screen. add changes in `activity_leanback_details.xml` or `DetailsSupportFragment` container Activity layout  :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- DetailsSupportFragment container -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/details_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/extra_line"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/extra_line"
        android:text="Extra Line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```